Let $\alpha, \beta$ be the roots of $x^2-a_1x+1=0$, and consider the sequence of numbers $a_r(r\ge0)$ with $a_0=1$ and $a^2_{r+1}=1+a_r.a_{r+2}$
Let $\alpha, \beta$ are roots of equation $x^2-a_1 x+1=0$ and consider sequence of numbers $a_r,\;r\geq0\;$ with $a_0=1\;$ and $a_{r+1}^2=1+a_r\cdot a_{r+2}.\;$ Then which of the following is/are true?
(A) $a_r+a_{r+2}=a_1 \cdot a_{r+1}$
(B) $a_r+a_{r+2}=2\cdot a_{r+1}$
(C) $a_n=\dfrac{\alpha^{n+1}-\beta^{n+1}}{\alpha-\beta}$
(D) $a_n=\dfrac{\alpha^{n+1}+\beta^{n+1}}{\alpha+\beta}$
The answer is option A, C.
The solution for option A is given on this thread using option C.
I wonder what the proof for option C is.
My Attempt:
Putting $n=1$ is enough to show that option D can't be the answer. Also, option C gets satisfied.
$a_1=\alpha+\beta$
And sum of roots is indeed $a_1$.
Let the result be true for $n=k$
i.e. $a_k=\frac{\alpha^{k+1}-\beta^{k+1}}{\alpha-\beta}$
To prove it for $n=k+1$,
$\frac{\alpha^{k+2}-\beta^{k+2}}{\alpha-\beta}=\frac{\alpha^k(a_1\alpha-1)-\beta^k(a_1\beta-1)}{\alpha-\beta}=\frac{a_1\alpha^{k+1}-\alpha^k-a_1\beta^{k+1}+\beta^k}{\alpha-\beta}=\frac{a_1(\alpha^{k+1}-\beta^{k+1})-(\alpha-\beta)}{\alpha-\beta}=\frac{a_1(a_k)(\alpha-\beta)-(\alpha-\beta)}{\alpha-\beta}=a_1\cdot a_k-1$
Not able to conclude.

Try to show your thoughts and work or this post will be downvoted and closed by others ;)

@Maxime, give me 10mins.

@Maxime I have edited further.

The claim holds for $n=0$ and $n=1$, since $a_1=\alpha+\beta$, by well-known relations between roots and coefficients. Then we prove it by induction. Having $a_n=\frac{\alpha^{n+1}-\beta^{n+1}}{\alpha-\beta}$ for $n=k$ and $n=k+1$, we want to prove it for $n=k+2$. It suffices to compute $a_{k+2}=\frac{a_{k+1}^2-1}{a_k}$ and to remember that $\alpha \beta = 1$.
Explicitly,
$$a_{k+2}=\frac{a_{k+1}^2-1}{a_k}=\frac{\left(\frac{\alpha^{k+2}-\beta^{k+2}}{\alpha-\beta}\right)^2-1}{\frac{\alpha^{k+1}-\beta^{k+1}}{\alpha-\beta}}=\frac{(\alpha^{k+2}-\beta^{k+2})^2-(\alpha-\beta)^2}{(\alpha-\beta)(\alpha^{k+1}-\beta^{k+1})}=\frac{\alpha^{2k+4}+\beta^{2k+4}-\alpha^2-\beta^2}{(\alpha-\beta)(\alpha^{k+1}-\beta^{k+1})}$$
I want to show that it is equal to $\frac{a^{k+3}-\beta^{k+3}}{\alpha-\beta}$, that is $\alpha^{2k+4}+\beta^{2k+4}-\alpha^2-\beta^2=(\alpha^{k+3}-\beta^{k+3})(\alpha^{k+1}-\beta^{k+1})$, and this holds by simply expanding.

Mind showing the working?

@aarbee Added the explicit computation.

Thanks, means a lot.
